# passing extra info to multer Upload API

Tags: angularjs, node.js, multer

I am using the multer way for upload in node.js, explained in detail here https://ciphertrick.com/2015/12/07/file-upload-with-angularjs-and-nodejs/

I am trying to pass another information with requested data which is called **invoiceId**:

```
Upload.upload({
                    url: 'http://localhost:4000/api/ubiq/listInvoiceAttachedFiles/attach', //webAPI exposed to upload the file
                    data: {file: file, invoiceId:invoiceId} //pass file as data, should be user ng-model
                }).then(function (resp) { //upload function returns a promise
                    if (resp.data.error_code === 0) { //validate success
                        $window.alert('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + ' uploaded');
                        console.log(resp.config.data.file); ....etc
```

But I am getting req.body empty on the server side:

```
/** API path that will upload the files */

  server.post('/api/ubiq/listInvoiceAttachedFiles/attach', function(req, res) {

    console.log(req.body);

        security.verifyPermission("/api/ubiq/listInvoiceAttachedFiles/attach", req.session.currentUser, true /*isInSession*/).then(function (successInfo) {
            if (!successInfo.isAllowed) {
                console.log('not allowed');
                return res.json(apiHelp.notAllowed());
            }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should pass as post parameters not with file

Comment: Dipak chavda you mean via $http.post?

Comment: I have used different way of multer of diskstorage() method , can I post that way probably that may helpful??

Comment: Why not, thanks in advance

Comment: Please review and let me know if any difficulty finds

Comment: Let me know if you face any issue while you are implementing. I shall try to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multer re-attaches the body object within the callback of the upload function.

Your data should be available after this line. 
https://github.com/rahil471/file-upload-with-angularjs-and-nodejs/blob/master/server/app.js#L35

Comment: Wow Mr. Rahil, it was simpler than expected :)

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet is my working code and I have tested and used multiple time in my application.

Multer have two storage engines:

1. DiskStorage
2. MemoryStorage

I have used DiskStorage, which gives more control over disk storage on file.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express()
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require("multer");

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, dirPath);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var datetimestamp = Date.now() + Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - 99999999999 + 1)) + 9999999999999;         
        cb(null, datetimestamp + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length - 1].toLowerCase());
    }
});
var infoUpload = multer({storage: storage});

router
        .route(API_PATH)
        .post(infoUpload.array("file"), function (req, res) {
            console.log(req.body);
        });
```

Following are few links which give you a brief explanation.

http://derpturkey.com/node-multipart-form-data-explained/

http://alexkatz.me/posts/image-upload-with-node-and-multer/

Hope it may help to resolve an issue.